# Rust UNDER windshield

Tags: rust, windshield, lexus, windshield-molding

I have some rust under my windshield at the top edge where the trim is usually black.  The rust is showing through the windshield when looking from outside the vehicle.  Should I be worried about this, and how can I go about repair?  Can I just apply sealer from the outside to prevent this from getting worse?

This is for a 2006 Lexus IS250.

[image: Windshield rust]

Comment: An image of what you're talking about would go a long way. If it is what I'm thinking, the only way to "fix it" is to remove the windshield and have a body shop clean it up. Once it starts rusting, you aren't going to stop it until there's no metal left.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'll take a picture when I get home.  Do you think I could get away with just applying some silicone sealant to the trim to prevent further rust?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I have updated the post with a picture.

Comment: Is it just me or doesn't the top of the windshield suppose to have a piece of weather stripping with adhesive on it in that crack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show in the picture actually looks like the windshield is delaminating. As you are probably aware, the windshield is made up of two layers of glass with a layer of (something) in between which makes it so it won't shatter when impacted. And by shatter, I mean it will crack and all, but won't become a billion pieces of glass all over the occupants. Anyway, this is exactly what it looks like when these layers start to separate. The only fix for it is to get the windshield replaced. Even if there is rust behind where the delamination is taking place, you'll still need to get the windshield replaced at some point to fix the issue.

You cannot fix this with sealer. The windshield will continue to delaminate.

Comment: Yes, the black is the interior surface of the windscreen, damage in front of the black is damage to the screen.

Comment: Upon further inspection, it looks like you were right.  The windshield is just delaminating.  The rust isn't under the windshield, it looks like there's a bit of metal between two layers of the windshield which is rusting.

Answer (score 2):

If you car has airbags I would not recommend just using a sealant. Airbags depend on the windscreen fitting securely in place.

If you do need to use a sealant ensure it is designed for vehicle windscreens. A normal silicone designed for bathrooms might actually increase the rust.

Rust is like cancer for cars, it will keep spreading even if you put sealant over it. For your own safety rather have this fixed now as the rust will get worse.

Have the windscreen removed, remove all paint from the effected area, see how bad the rust is and get a body shop to repair it. You could try repair it yourself but this depends on how deep the rust is. If it's just surface rust you could do it yourself however if the rust is already through a panel you'll need professional help.

Comment: Added a picture.  What do you think?  I was just planning on using Permatex Flowable Silicone Windshield and Glass Sealer...  I've also heard that there are things you can use to prevent rust from growing.  The windshield isn't leaking into the cabin.

Comment: The fact it is not leaking yet is a good thing. There are products you can use to help prevent the rust spreading but it might still require you to remove some of the excess paint and rust. The keyword is help, it's not a fail safe. IMO the only real way to remove rust is to sand, grind and cut it out.

Comment: but judging by your photo the rust really is not that bad. If money(re-spraying the panel) is an issue you might be able to get away with having the rust repaired/removed, spraying some primer and having it covered with a "wrap" in the section that you have to repair.